# How do I get all content on site to move once drop-down menu is opened?

Tags: html, css

I want all content `div`s to move down once the drop down menu is opened and then move back up once it is closed. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<i><div class="Navigation" style="position:relative;left:170px;max-width:100%;border:none;padding:0;margin:0 auto;display:block;">

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar openclosemenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">         
                    <div class="menu-icon">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-icon menu-text">
                        Menu
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">

                    <div id="smoothmenu1" class="ddsmoothmenu Navigation">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li id="page-id-1" class="#">
                                <a title="Home" href="index.html">Naslovna</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="page-id-2" class="about-us">
                                <a title="#" href="#">O Nama</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="page-id-290" class="#"><a title="#" href="#">Test 1</a></li>
                                    <li id="page-id-169" class="#"><a title="#" href="#">Test 2</a></li>
                                    <li id="page-id-18" class="#"><a title="#" href="#">Test 3</a></li>
                                    <li id="page-id-155" class="#"><a title="#" href="#">Test 3</a></li>
                                    <li id="page-id-1558" class="#"><a title="#" href="#">Test 3</a></li>
                                    <li id="page-id-18888" class="#"><a title="#" href="#">Test 3</a></li>
                                    <li id="page-id-185458" class="#"><a title="#" href="#">Test 3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li id="page-id-3" class="maternity">
                                <a title="#" href="#">Materinstvo</a>
                                <ul>            
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li id="page-id-4" class="children">
                                <a title="#" href="#">Dijeca</a>
                                <ul>                
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li id="page-id-5" class="womens-health">
                                <a title="#" href="#">Zdravlje Žene</a>
                                <ul>            
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li id="page-id-6" class="medical-professionals">
                                <a title="#" href="#">Bezbjednost</a>
                                <ul>        
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li id="page-id-7" class="careers">
                                <a title="#" href="#">Naši Doktori</a>
                                <ul>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <img src="prop.png" width="850" height="1" style="position:relative;left:-100px;">
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div></i>
```

My CSS for this element is:

```
<i>.ddsmoothmenu
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000000000000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li a { display: block; float: left }

.ddsmoothmenu ul li a { display: inline-block}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li
{
    display: list-item;
    float: left;
    clear: both
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li ul { top: 0 }

.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a
{
    width: 260px!important;
    line-height: 16px!important;
    padding: 8px!important;
    margin: 0;
    border-top-width: 0;
    font-size: 180%;
    font-family: "MyriadPro-Regular", MyriadPro-Regular;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #999999!important;
    text-align: left!important
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li ul li a
{
    width: 260px!important;
    line-height: 16px!important;
    padding: 8px!important;
    margin: 0;
    border-top-width: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: "MyriadPro-Regular", MyriadPro-Regular;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #999999!important;
    text-align: left!important
} 

.ddsmoothmenu {height: 1%}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `position: absolute;` here:

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
```

Will cause those elements to be on top of others.
Remove the `position` and it should then force the items below it down on the page.

If that doesn't work, then please try to reproduce it on jsFiddle or jsBin so we can play around with it and see the full working code.

Comment: Hello

First thank you for your time helping me, i have tryed your position code and it still wont push divs down it just moves all navigation tabs into one, can you please check my code i will upload it to sendspace, i am newbie so i dont know how to properly use jsBin.

Here is my file: https://www.sendspace.com/file/zim1o2

It Contains all files for html/css.